# Prerequieries and refrences for Stanley-Reisner Ring

Tags: algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra

I need to study about topological properties of stanley reisner rings but I'm so lost in finding refrences.
I know a little algebraic topology and I know Abstract algebra (groups, rings, fields, modules, ...) but I don't know much about commutative algebra and I've heard that I need it.
I would be super thankful if you could recommend some refrences (books, articles or anything that can possibly lead me to other sources.)